# In Django, does `queryset is None` evaluates the queryset?

Tags: python, django

Is Django `queryset` evaluated in below cases? If **no**, then why?

#### 1.

```py
if queryset is None:
    pass
```

#### 2.

```py
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
    pass
```

Is it because in both the cases python performs object reference comparison, which does not lead to a query?

Comment: Nothing will be evaluated here. `if queryset is None` is not at all the same thing as `if not queryset`.

Comment: is it because by using `is`, python is performing object comparison rather than value? And what about the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), a queryset is evaluated when you try to access its values - by iterating over it (directly or indirectly), subscribing/slicing it, printing it (actually: calling `repr()` on it) or testing it's truth value.

`is` is the identity operator, it compares objects identifiers, so it doesn't evaluate the queryset.

`isinstance` checks the object's class (and the class mro), so it doesn't evaluate the queryset either.